# Value of variable in django template tags

Tags: django, django-templates

I have written a custom template tag which returns a number of users in the chat.

`{% chat_online chat_channel %}`

However, token seems to receive the value as `chat_channel` instead of the value of that variable.

What's the matter?

Comment: How can we possibly tell you what's wrong with your custom tag unless you show us the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that template tags definitions (`{% ... %}`)in your HTML are just pieces text being parsed by django's template engine, so you need to [tell django to actually lookup the variable in the context being rendered with the name `chat_channel`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag). This example from the docs is quite clear:

```
class FormatTimeNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, date_to_be_formatted, format_string):
        self.date_to_be_formatted = template.Variable(date_to_be_formatted)
        ...

    def render(self, context):
        try:
            actual_date = self.date_to_be_formatted.resolve(context)
            ...
        except template.VariableDoesNotExist:
            return ''
```

where `template.Variable(date_to_be_formatted)` is creating a template variable from the raw value passed to the template tag (`blog_entry.date_updated` in the example) and `self.date_to_be_formatted.resolve(context)` is finding the actual value of that variable in the template by resolving it against the context.